# Running gradle specifying the absolute path of a task interprets the names as commands

Tags: bash, gradle, cygwin

For this question, I'll be using the sample project `water` included in the source distribution of Gradle. (See [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#ssub:filtering_by_properties).)

> The code for this example can be found at `samples/userguide/multiproject/tropicalWithProperties/water` in the ‘`-all`’ distribution of Gradle.

---

Sometimes when using `bash` in Cygwin, when I run `gradle` specifying the absolute (logical) path of the task I want to execute, something bizarre happens:

```sh
$ gradle :bluewhale:hello
```

```
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Gradle/bin/gradle: line 153: bluewhale: command not found
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Gradle/bin/gradle: line 153: hello: command not found
<-------------> 0% CONFIGURING [56ms]
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task '.' not found in root project 'water'.

* Try:
Run gradle tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run
with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

The first two lines of output indicate that bash or gradle interpreted the text after a colon as commands. Moreover, no actual task seems to be passed to gradle (`Task '.' not found in root project 'water'.`). This is confirmed by a further example:

```sh
$ gradle :"echo foo":pwd
```

```
foo
/cygdrive/c/Users/Paolo/Desktop/Sandbox/water

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Task '.' not found in root project 'water'.

[...]
```

What makes this even more strange is that it is inconsistent: when I restart my laptop the problem disappears. I would add more debugging information but I have no clue where to start.

As far as I'm aware, the problem, once it appears, is shell-wide. Any Cygwin `bash` session will have the same problem.

---

This works fine when using Windows' command line `cmd`, so I'm thinking it has to do with Cygwin or Cygwin's `bash`.

The problem is not dependent on having a space in `gradle`'s path (`Program Files`).

Comment: Have you tried to install in a Directory that does not contain space in the name as `Program Files` ?

Comment: @matzeri The problem persists even without spaces in the path.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem, but it only occurred when `gradlew` was being called in an automated fashion by Jenkins on Windows worker nodes (via Cygwin).

The source of the problem was a `find` call being made by the `gradlew` script as part of its cygwin compatibility logic. It turns out that `C:\Windows\System32` appeared on my `PATH` env var before `C:\cygwin64\bin`, so `gradlew` was actually running the windows `find` command rather than the unix one. The booched find call ultimately resulted in the mangling of all arguments that contained a colon.

I was able to solve the problem by modifying our Windows nodes to *prepend* rather than *append* the cygwin bin path to the `PATH` env var. Guessing that you are suffering from a similar `PATH`-related issue.

One possible alternate explanation is that your `IFS` env var got set to `:`, but I suspect that would result in a slightly different-looking error.